# Read select=multiple not working

Tags: javascript

I have a multi select option filed like the follows;

```
<select name="cars" id="carsId" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" onclick="readValues()">
```

I need to read all the values into an array on readValues function. The array shopuld be like

```
A = [Volvo,Saab,opel,audi]
```

Please help me guys!!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330030/javascript-get-values-from-multiple-select-option-box

Comment: @Exlord I checked that, its another case!!

Comment: do you mean all the options and not just the selected once or just the selected once?

Comment: @Exlord I need all the values from that field into an array. Hope you got it!!

Comment: The question @Exlord has linked to should tell you all you need to know. Don't create a string, just add the values to the array.

Comment: See http://edu-kinect.com/blog/2014/06/20/jquery-multiselect-dropdown-list-with-checkboxes-or-multiple-select-dropdown-with-checkboxes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this also:

```
var readValues = function () {
    var options = document.getElementById('carsId').options;
    var list = [],
        i = options.length;
    while (i--) {
        list.push(options[i].value);
    }
    console.log(list);//<-- ["audi", "opel", "saab", "volvo"] 
};
```

In-case you need the text shown to user, use `list.push(options[i].innerHTML);`

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp

```
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
var options = [];
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  {
     options.push(x.options[i].value);// or .text for the text
  }
```

with jquery :
[How to get all options of a select using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590163/how-to-get-all-options-of-a-select-using-jquery)

```
 var options = [];
$("#id option").each(function()
{
    options.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

If you're using jQuery you can try following

**jQuery solution**

```
function readValuesJQuery(){
    var A = $("select option").map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(A);
}
```

**OR**

**javascript solution**

```
function readValuesJavascript(){
   var ddlArray= new Array();
   var ddl = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
   for (i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) {
      ddlArray[i] = ddl .options[i].value;
   }
   console.log(ddlArray);
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uLfp4rkz/2/)

Comment: @downvoter It's a good practice to mention the reason for downvote!

Answer (score 1):

using jQuery:

```
function readValues() {
    var values = [];
    $('[name="cars"] option').each(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
    });
    return values;
}
```

using pure javascript:

```
var readValues = function () {
    var options = document.getElementById('carsId').children;
    var values = [];
    for(i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
        values.push(options[i].value);
    }
    console.log(values);
    return values;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q94ndrcc/

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged here!

Comment: @fish_ball it well reurn only selected values. I need all!

Answer (score 1):

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10052006/select-multiple-values-in-a-multiple-select-box-with-jquery)

```
$("#sel").click(function(e) { // when link clicked
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#foo option:selected ").each(function() {
        var v = $(this).attr("value"); // first select's value
        $('#bar option').each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == v) { 
                $(this).attr("selected",true); // select if same value
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following its working.

HTML

```
<select name="cars" id="carsId" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="getValue">
```

Script: jQuery 1.9.1

```
//1. for selected value:
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btnClick').click(function(){
         var selText = [];
         $("#carsId option:selected").each(function () {
           var $this = $(this);
           if ($this.length) {
            selText.push($this.text());
           }
        });
          alert(selText);
    });
});

//2. get all value without any selection:

 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#btnClick').click(function(){
         var selText = [];
         $("#carsId option").each(function () {
           var $this = $(this);
           if ($this.length) {
            selText.push($this.text());
           }
        });
          alert(selText);
      });
  });
```

**[Running Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q94ndrcc/8/)**